# Using OpenID with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, openid, authlogic, authlogic-oid

Are there any updated tutorials for using OpenID with Authlogic? I'd heard good things about Authlogic, and the documentation makes it seem much better than Restful Authentication... but in trying to implement OpenID, 100% of the tutorials and information I've come across have been outdated (including Railscast #170). They depend on gems that either no longer work or no longer exist. And to add to the frustration, Github has been down for hours today.

Does anyone know of a simple updated guide to get OpenID working with Authlogic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (if you're on Rails 2.3.8 like I am) is to use older versions of pretty much everything. I fond this app and simply copied the versions of the gems they were using: https://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example. That meant using the authlogic_openid plugin rather than the gem form.

Things worked well after that.

Comment: What if you are on Rails 3? Any info on that?